# No puedo acceder a los atributos de la respuesta de un find()

Tags: javascript, nodejs

```js
export const destroy = async ({ params }, res, next) =>{
  var visitaVar

  await Visita.findById(params.id)
    .then(notFound(res))
    .then((visita) => {
      visitaVar = visita
      visita.remove()})
      .catch(next)

  await Alumno.find({'visitas.fecha': visitaVar.fecha})
  .then(alumno =>{
        console.log("Alumno =>" + alumno)
        console.log("Alumno visitas => " + alumno.visitas)
    for (let index = 0; index < alumno.visitas.length; index++) {
      const element = alumno.visitas[index];
        if(element == visitaVar.fecha)
          alumno.visitas.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return alumno.save()
  })
    .then(success(res, 204))
    .catch(next)
  }
```

El problema es que el primer console.log de alumno me devuelve lo siguiente

```js
Alumno =>{ _id: 5c90e4b23c3b1d31c67c2582,
  nombre: 'Cristobal',
  email: 'cristobal@gmail.com',
  telefono: 987456123,
  tutor: 5c90c73e7c9d2d1ebf231487,
  visitas:
   [ { realizada: false,
       _id: 5c90e5243c3b1d31c67c2584,
       titulo: 'Otra visita5',
       fecha: 2019-03-25T09:00:00.000Z },
     { realizada: false,
       _id: 5c90e64173201e32a7877705,
       titulo: 'Otra visita7',
       fecha: 2019-03-26T09:00:00.000Z }],
  createdAt: 2019-03-19T12:46:42.958Z,
  updatedAt: 2019-03-19T19:20:20.503Z,
  __v: 7 }
```

Y el siguiente console.log de alumno.visitas obtengo lo siguiente

```js
Alumno visitas => undefined
```

He probado con los demas campos y no entiendo por que me devuelve undefined. ¿Es por que estoy accediendo mal a los atributos?.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a comprobar si la variable `visitaVar` tiene valor?

Yo lo trataría de hacer sin async/await, y haría una mezcla de *callbacks* y *promises*. Es decir, la consulta sobre Vistia la haría con un *callback* (es decir, usando el método `exec`, ya que te garantiza que se invocará cuando se haya realizado la consulta); la consulta sobre Alumno la puedes realizar ya con el clásico *thenable* de mongoose (`.then(...)`) o con un nuevo *callback* (dos niveles de callbacks no llegan a ser del todo un infierno).

Ánimo y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo cambiando el find por un findOne, aparte la comparación de fechas dentro del for esta mal y deberia ser

```js
if(element.fecha.getTime() === visitaVar.fecha.getTime())
```